# Sentence correction help

Tags: sentence-construction

Which of the below statements is correct and why?

> This practice was brought **in** to prevent certain abuses.

or

> This practice was brought **about** to prevent certain abuses.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence "This was brought in to prevent certain abuses" sounds OK.

When something is brought in, it means that it's introduced to do something; this phrase fits well in the sentence.  On the other hand, the phrase "to bring eomething about" means to cause something to happen.  For example, "His reckless spending brought about the ruin of the company".
This phrase doesn't make sense in the sentence presented by the OP.